# Is there a term for creating a new meaning for an existing word?

Tags: verbs, neologisms

I'm looking for a technical term for using a noun as its own verb form where such usage is not extant. For example, using *intellect* as a verb (to intellect). Is there such a term? It doesn't seem to be a neologism or an example of metonymy.

Comment: You should have left your comments up for longer. I was in stitches.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You got the answer.

Comment: And amazingly quickly. I am impressed.

Comment: Ha ha. It's very quick. English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

Comment: And asked and answered on ELU **twice** before. I'm not impressed.

Comment: I did do some research, and I looked for duplicate questions on EL&U. Unfortunately, the best way to search Stack Exchange is to use Google. That's how I come across most duplicate questions.

Comment: @Mick It's extremely difficult to find duplicate by *search* here. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Rathony Perhaps that's why we get so many duplicated questions?

Comment: @Mick Unless Stack Exchange introduces a system run by *Artificial Intelligence* to automatically check for duplicates, there is no way we can stop users from asking duplicate questions. Also, most of the OPs, especially new, don't care about duplicate. They want just answers! That's quite understandable. What is a Q&A site for?

Comment: @Rathony I understand that. I have asked questions before and the software has offered some questions as possible duplicates, but this time - nada. No matter.

Comment: @Mick The onus is certainly not on new(-ish) contributors to do more than a quick reasonable check for duplicates, but someone using the terms 'verbing', 'zero derivation' should be able to find their way around and do a backwards check for duplicates. A close-vote for duplication need not reflect on the newish enquirer, but is needed in the interests of the site. 'I'm not impressed' was directed in parallel with your comment, not back to yourself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have no complaint. It's just a little ironic that in order to perform an effective search for possible duplicates, you (sometimes) need to know the answer to your own question.

Comment: @All - I think I'll delete this question. Water under the bridge and all that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most specific term for what you describe is [*verbification* or *verbing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verbing). The general term for using a word with one part of speech as another part of speech (not necessarily noun → verb) is *conversion* or *zero derivation* in linguistics and *[anthimeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria)* in rhetoric.

Comment: *Anthimeria* sounds perfect, and the example given, "The little old lady turtled along the road," is delightful.

Comment: Please check for duplicates where they might be considered likely before rushing to add an answer. Duplicates make the site look unprofessional.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not easy for relatively new users to check for duplicates. I don't agree duplicates make the site look unprofessional.

Comment: @Rathony It's easy enough to search for 'verbing', as I did. I'd not buy a grammar which repeated the same stuff every 300 pages. And perhaps our most valuable contributor here has mentioned the fact that repeat questions are not filtered out adequately.  Why do you think there is the 'duplicate' close vote reason?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, I also searched for duplicates. But as I said, relatively new users are not fully aware of how this site works. They don't even know they are supposed to post an answer to the duplicate master. I think it is too much to request they sholud search every single word they use in their answer.

Comment: Rathony This user certainly does now. And you're being ridiculous; the bolded terms in "The most specific term for what you describe is **verbification** or **verbing**. The general term for using a word with one part of speech as another part of speech (not necessarily noun → verb) is **conversion** or **zero derivation**" are the sensible ones to search for. All will lead to duplicates.  // What does / did 'The answer was in the linked question' mean? Why did _you_ not bother to close-vote?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why am I being ridiculous? You are asserting that this answerer must have searched the key words in the search before posting this answer. Yeah. It would have been better and nicer, but you can't blame him for posting this answer. How many users search key words before asking or answering a question except for very experienced users like yourself or me? They will learn. Let's move on. But duplicates don't make this site look unprofessional. I don't see any relevance there. Also, do you really think ELU is professional with all those lousy and low-quality crap here?

Comment: This is all very instructive. Now I know how new quaerants must sometimes feel.

Comment: Sorry about this. I don't know what I should do. Surely only admins are able to close a question as a duplicate?

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler The question was closed by the OP. Case closed. Don't worry.

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler Quaerants can do that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Rathony 'I think it is too much to request they should [sic] search every single word they use in their answer.' was the ridiculous statement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You can't change the way users behave here on ELU alone or with your crusade. A Meta discussion here.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/what-is-with-people-who-answer-questions-that-are-known-to-be-dupes I agree with the two most upvoted answers **absolutamente**.

Comment: @Rathony I see that for some reason you fail to mention that the question on Meta addressing the issue (and speaking against the non-voiding of rep upvotes for answers to duplicates) received three times as many upvotes as those two answers you mention put together.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The reason I didn't mention it is very obvious. It has not been implemented. That's for sure.