# What's the English Technique called when you change a word's word class?

Tags: puns

For example:

- My table is accepting deals, so it's an acceptable.
- My table is counting, so it's an accountable.

I understand these aren't very rewarding wordplay sentences but I want to know the technique, so it can be applied in better context for enjoyment.

Basically, acceptable is normally an adjective, but it's being used as a noun here.

Comment: "Acceptable" is not a noun nor is it being used like a noun in your example.

Comment: I forgot to an 'an' - but more to the point do you have the answer?

Comment: Please update your question if the current one is not exactly what you mean.

Comment: Your examples don't take into account the passive nature of such formations. That which can be delivered is "a deliverable". That which delivers is not a deliverable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a term for the use of adjectives as nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305305/is-there-a-term-for-the-use-of-adjectives-as-nouns) Or in general [any  English terms for 'to change the part of speech of a word without applying modification?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437448/any-english-terms-for-to-change-the-part-of-speech-of-a-word-without-applying)? ...

Comment: Or [Is there a term for creating a new meaning for an existing word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355469/is-there-a-term-for-creating-a-new-meaning-for-an-existing-word)? etc etc (conversion; zero derivation ...)

Answer (score 1):

The technical term for this in linguistics is **conversion.** As [Wikipedia explains:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation))

> In linguistics, **conversion,** also called **zero derivation** or **null derivation,** is a kind of word formation involving the creation of a word (of a new part of speech) from an existing word (of a different part of speech) without any change in form [...] For example, the noun *green* in golf (referring to a putting-green) is derived ultimately from the adjective *green.*

Comment: Please check for likely duplicates .